# realtime statistics script

Tags: javascript, counting

I'm sure you know the case in which [gmail](http://mail.google.com/mail/) shows the free storage on the "Lots of space" paragraph when you are on the login page. There is a counter running on that page and I'm curious to know how it works. Can me give me some pointers, links, tutorials, reads, explanations?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that is a "fake" counter based on stats, not an actual measure of the actual available space. The comment `// Estimates of nanite storage generation over time.` above the block that defines the CP array is a strong pointer

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source for that page you will find that it is a simple javascript function that just updates the number once a second. There is no magic involved and it is **not** live data in any way, just an estimate.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code in charge of it. Looks like it is based on a time computation being mapped to a number of Bytes.

```
function updateQuota() {
  if (!quota_elem) {
  return;
  }
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < CP.length; i++) {
    if (now < CP[i][0]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i == 0) {
    setTimeout(updateQuota, 1000); 
  } else if (i == CP.length) {
    quota_elem.innerHTML = CP[i - 1][1];
  } else {
    var ts = CP[i - 1][0];
    var bs = CP[i - 1][1];
    quota_elem.innerHTML = format(((now-ts) / (CP[i][0]-ts) * (CP[i][1]-bs)) + bs); 
    setTimeout(updateQuota, 1000); 
  } 
} 

var PAD = '.000000';
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a nice slideshow here

http://www.slideshare.net/kuchmuch/gmails-quota-secrets

Detailing how it works.

It is as mentioned just a date set to a predefined size, which the ticker then counts towards.